# Can't find how to center my ads. I have tried align="center" and margin:auto but nothing works.

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="537267839_INSERT_SLOT_ID_HERE" 
style="width:768px;height:90px;margin:auto;">

 <noscript>
  <p align="center">
    <iframe id="a1651026db" name="a1651026db" src="//oncampusweb-d.openx.net/w/1.0/afr?auid=537267839&cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE"frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="728" height="90" align="center"display:block;>
 <a href="//oncampusweb-d.openx.net/w/1.0/rc?cs=a1651026db&cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE" ><img src="//oncampusweb-d.openx.net/w/1.0/ai?auid=537267839&cs=a1651026db&cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE" border="0" alt=""></a>
 </p>
 </iframe></noscript>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
 var OX_ads = OX_ads || [];
    OX_ads.push({
    slot_id: "537267839_INSERT_SLOT_ID_HERE",
    auid: "537267839"
});
</script>




   <script type="text/javascript" src="//oncampusweb-d.openx.net/w/1.0/jstag"> 
 </script>
```

In this code I want to center the ad being placed. I can't figure out how. I tried align="center" in style and margin:auto but it doesnt work.

Comment: Have you tried using flex ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

0 for the top/bottom and auto for left/right

Comment: In the margin definition of the style

Comment: Did not change anything.

Comment: your iframe have attribute errors, see the display: block, it should be like this: align="center" style="display:block;"> I just opened the page here and is centered width  margin: 0 auto https://ibb.co/d4xPxU

Answer (score 0):

Try using a flex box to center align child components both vertically and horizontally.

```
<div id="537267839_INSERT_SLOT_ID_HERE" 
style="width:768px;height:90px;display:flex;justify 
content:center;align-items:center;">
```

Comment: Am i supposed to replace the top line with that or place it separately? Replacing did not do anything.

Comment: Joe closing tags are incorrect. iframe should be closed within p tag see to it.

Comment: Fixed those. Still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it:

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center">
your code goes here
</div>
```

Comment: Did not fix it. Thanks though!

Comment: Ok new problem. That looks great, exactly what I want. Any idea why it wont show up when pasted into wordpress?

Comment: I think you have another wrapper element that is giving another style. I think you have to share your code.